# Rails 3.2 RSpec test for before_destroy hook fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I have two models:

```
class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :acol, :dependent => :nullify
  before_destroy :check_acol_presence
private 
  def check_acol_presence
    if acol
      errors.add(:base,"activerecord.errors.models.region.delete_with_existing_acol")
      return false
    end
  end
end

class Acol < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
end
```

I want to check the 'check_acol_presence' hook in RSpec test. So here is the test code:

```
region = FactoryGirl.create(:region)
acol = FactoryGirl.create(:acol, :region => region)
region.reload
region.destroy
lambda { region.reload }.should_not raise(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
```

In rails console this check works just fine. But the test fails. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Try to put before_destroy line before has_one line

Comment: old post but it worked to move the before_destroy ahead of the has_many... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be raise_error, not just raise:

```
lambda { region.reload }.should_not raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
```

Otherwise, your test itself was probably *raising* the error.